# mysql_insert_id without modifying the db

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to this. Is there anyway to get the last auto increment id without changing the db?

`$check = mysql_insert_id();`

I tried Max(), but it gave pretty much the same result...

Comment: No. `mysql_insert_id()` and mySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` apply to the current connection only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
SELECT Auto_increment 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='<your table name>'
  AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id() is the correct Method.  Max() does only return the highest id value of your database table, but that dont have to be the latest inserted id. You understand?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

The `FOR UPDATE` is because I'm guessing you want to follow this up with an `INSERT`. If this is the case, do it in the same transaction and I would recommend specifying an explicit value for `id` rather than relying on `AUTOINCREMENT`.